# How can I make IntelliJ plus on other side

Tags: intellij-idea

When I am inside a class in IntelliJ and ALT+INS toString method I get this:
[image]

However I want the plus to be on the oposite site, like this:

[image]

How Can i Configure IntelliJ to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Binary expressions | [x] Operation sign on next line